Tmux bind-key second command stops working for no reason
I have a tmux key binding to move windows left or right as follows:
# window movement (swap)
bind-key P swap-window -t -1 \; select-window -t -1
bind-key N swap-window -t +1 \; select-window -t +1

As you can see, each binding has two commands. The first swaps a window with and adjacent one, the second moves to that window. The effect is that the window moves in the status bar but not the view.
The problem is that the second command just stops working after some time and I end up swapping the window but not moving. Once I run tmux source .tmux.conf the problem is fixed, but it is annoying having to run it from time to time.
Is there anything wrong with my binding or a better way to achieve the intended behavior?

"Is there […] a better way to achieve the intended behavior?" – swap-window -d, I think. I'm not posting an answer because I feel that a good answer shall also solve the mystery of the bindings that stop working.
